# Наследование моделей в Codeigniter

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, codeigniter

Каким образом можно создать модель расширенную от своего абстрактного класса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В application/core/ создать MY_Model.php и наследовать её от CI_Model.

```
<?php
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

   function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
   }
}
```

А в applicaton/models уже создавать модель наследованную от пользовательской модели

```
<?php
class Auth_Model extends MY_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

И в `application/config/config.php` добавить

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

Comment: А если хочется в папке модел Абстрактный касс модели сделать и таких моделей несколько будет?

Comment: В модели без костылей это не получиться